# Multifield inside multifield

Tags: dialog, aem

Below is my dialog.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
        title="CQ Dialog"
        xtype="dialog">
        <items
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            xtype="tabpanel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <tab1
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                    title="Tab 1">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <addcolumn
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            fieldDescription="Click + to add column"
                            fieldLabel="Add column"
                            name="./addcolumn"
                            xtype="multicompositefield">
                            <fieldConfigs jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <countrydetails
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Click + to add country details"
                                    fieldLabel="Add country details"
                                    name="./countrydetails"
                                    xtype="multifield">
                                    <fieldConfig
                                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                        hideLabel="false"
                                        xtype="multifieldpanel">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                            <countryname
                                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                                fieldLabel="Country name"
                                                name="./countryname"
                                                width="200"
                                                xtype="textfield"/>
                                            <countryicon
                                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                                fieldLabel="Country icon"
                                                name="./countryicon"
                                                width="200"
                                                xtype="pathfield"/>
                                            <linkurl
                                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                                fieldLabel="Link url"
                                                name="./linkurl"
                                                width="200"
                                                xtype="pathfield"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </fieldConfig>
                                </countrydetails>
                            </fieldConfigs>
                        </addcolumn>
                    </items>
                </tab1>
            </items>
        </items>
    </jcr:root>
```

I was just trying to create multifield inside another multifield. 
    Issue I am facing is, once I filled the dialog field with values and when I reopen the dialog, all fields and filled data is cleared and dialog is empty.

```
Any suggestions what went wrong in my dialog

Thanks
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice complex constructs like these. Either write your own widget that takes care of some of the complexity or do the nesting with an inner parsys of the main component where you can only add specialized sub-components.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but not just with the dialog structure you posted. You have to take care of field value serialisation for nested components.

Your values are blanking out because the value map handling of widgets is not compatible with nested values. A good read is at:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/nested_multifield.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have gone through the link u have given. 
How can I add 3 fields inside this countrydetails multifield

 this.countrydetails= new CQ.form.MultiField({
            fieldLabel : "Country details",
            
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                },
                dialogclose : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                },
            }
        });
        this.add(this.countrydetails);

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing. There is a cleaner way to do it via dialogue structure and extending the ext js to store/read properties as nodes rather than JSON in multi-field nesting. It requires 6.1+ though IIRC. See http://experience-aem.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/aem-61-classic-ui-nested-composite-multifield-panel.html

Comment: Thanks again. But I could able to achieve this multifield inside multifield dialog creation. For this, instead of name property, I add property 'key' with value (For countryname field key property value is 'India') .

Comment: Then in the page node, data is saved like 

So in the page node the data is stored like 

{"countrydetails":["{\"countryname\":\"India\",\"countryicon\":\"/content/dam/mslife/Home-icon.png\",\"linkurl\":\"/content/commercial-us/neurology/tecfidera-myself/pat/en_us/home/events-desable\"}","{\"countryname\":\"Australia\",\"countryicon\":\"/content/dam/mslife/images.png\",\"linkurl\":\"/content/commercial-us/neurology/tecfidera-myself/pat/en_us/home/ambassadors\"}"]}

Someone I need to get the details from this.